# Referencing A Formula In Another Cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

Is it possible to enter formula text into a cell and then reference use that formula text in a other formula?

For example, I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP that changes which table it's looking at based on some other criteria. Instead of writing a cumbersome formula that includes the VLOOKUP formulas for each table I'll be referencing, I thought it might be a *little* easier to just have the VLOOKUP formulas in a table, and then write an IF statement that will determine which formula to use. Is it possible to say for example IF(A1=true, insert formula in D1, "")?

Comment: Doable with VBA as you describe it, but there's probably a way to simplify your formulas and just stick to that. Maybe add some sample data and the expected result, e.g. the cumbersome VLOOKUP formulas?

Comment: What is to stop you from just wrapping that IF around your formula, and leaving it like that?

Comment: Or you can use INDIRECT to create a dynamic reference to the correct table, based on your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are in the same format then you could switch it around and have the table name referenced by the VLOOKUP formula e.g. if you put a table name drop-down into A1 and your lookup value in B1 then used something like `=VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "[[COLUMN1]:[COLUMN5]]"),5,FALSE)` (untested)